# How do I make primary content in the right-rail SEO friendly?

Tags: seo

My site design has three rails: navigation on the left, user generated discussions in the center (liquid), and a primary editorial block in the right rail (no advertising). So, an article would be published by me and appear at the top of the right rail, and user comments would appear in the center rail.

I want search engines to see the right rail content as the primary content, and so the meta description for each page would be related to the right rail.

Is it possible to do this in an SEO friendly way?

[Note: an SEO consulting firm have implied to my boss that web crawlers only "care about the center rail", and if the meta information disagrees with center rail content they will ignore the page]

Comment: 80% of all SEO is bullshit, your boss should be aware of that fact, the SEO consulting firm is telling bullshit, big time.

Answer (score 1):

Search engines cannot see the page the way human users do. Search engines see just the html code of the page, so they cannot distinguish between left, center or right rails. They do, however, have a sense of were the header, the body and the footer of a page is.

When it comes to the body of a page, search engines tend to give more relevance to text which closer to the the top. So if you can have a block of text at the top of your html source, move it visually with CSS somewhere lower on the page, and still (probably) remain more relevant than other blocks of text.

However, there is no way to specify to search engines what your "primary content" of a page is. Search engines determine the relevancy of a page in relation to keywords based on a lot of different on-page signals, so you should focus on those.

As for the meta description, your boss should choose the SEO consulting firms more carefully, as what they recommended is actually a nonsense. Meta descriptions are only used (eventually) by Google (for example) to generate the snippet for your pages in search results. They have no value when in comes to rankings.

Here's two SEO facts regarding meta descriptions that come directly from Google: [Seo Fact NO.3](http://seo-fact.com/fact3/), [Seo Fact NO.4](http://seo-fact.com/fact4/)

Comment: >Search engines see just the html code of the page ... no, google stated various times (google webmaster channel youtube), that they render the content .. in some way (even execute some javascript). other than that i agree with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Positioning of visible content on a page is handled using CSS.

There's a number of different approaches available from using `float` to `position:absolute` etc. For SEO purposes, there's no single-best approach, as long as you have your article content appear closest to the `<body>` tag, before the other "rails" or "columns".